# Mysql LEFT JOIN ON penultimate id only

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this query trying to sum times:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.number, t1.time - COALESCE(SUM(t2.time), 0) time FROM times t1 
LEFT JOIN times t2 ON t1.number = t2.number AND t2.id < t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.number, t1.time
```

Output:

```
id          number          time (in seconds)
--------------------------------------------
1            9              65
2            5              78
3            7              92
```

It works fine, but I need to sum only with the penultimate id of the LEFT JOIN condition in the clause (`t2.id < t1.id`).

Comment: can you please post existing data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For selecting penultimate id

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.number, t1.time - COALESCE(SUM(t2.time), 0) time FROM times t1 
LEFT JOIN times t2 ON t1.number = t2.number 
AND t2.id = (select id from times order by id desc limit 1,1)
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.number, t1.time
```